# Resampling 30m DEM to 100m slope raster properly?

Tags: raster, dem, raster-conversion, slope

I need to resample a 30m DEM to a 100m slope raster.  Do I just resample the 30m DEM directly to the 100m slope raster? or, do I convert the 30m DEM to a 100m DEM and then create a 100m slope raster from the new 100m DEM file?

Comment: Are you after accuracy or visual appeal? Gut feeling is to resample the DEM and then make the slope, the resampling method (nearest, bilinear, cubic) may skew the slope results

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to resample the DEM and then create the slope layer.

Take a look at [this](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=3&f=40&t=116277) thread (particularly post 2) from the ESRI forums.

You might end up saving yourself some time this way as well.  Resampling a DEM will reduce it's size (in terms of disk space), and should allow the slope tool to process in a shorter amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try both and compare. Either will be a compromise on your higher resolution dataset. Hence, there is not 'proper' solution. Just be sure to detail the process you undertook so your work is repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can however; if you resample from smaller cell size to a larger cell size can result in the loss of data. If you resample from larger cell size to a smaller does not increase the resolution, it just creates more cells.